# Apenas anúncios de teste funcionam no AdMob

Tags: ionic, admob

Tentei adicionar o AdMob no Ionic 4 com vários tutoriais pela internet, mas nenhum está resolvendo o erro onde só os anúncios de teste estão aparecendo, quando eu coloco TRUE em isTesting. Quando eu coloco FALSE e adiciono o ID do anúncio, o mesmo não aparece.

O ID do meu AdMob já está no package.json, testei todos os tipos de anúncios do AdMob e nenhum funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, agora o anuncio só funciona com o apk assinado, não se preocupe, ao publicar seu banner vai aparecer no aplicativo.

segue um exemplo para te ajudar:

```js
 admob(){
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {      
      id:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      isTesting: false,
      autoShow: true      
      };
      this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
    
        this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
          .then(() => {
            if (this.infoNetwork.isConnect) {
            this.admobFree.banner.show().then(() => {
            }).catch(e => this.admobFree.banner.hide());
            }else{
              this.admobFree.banner.hide()
            }
          })
          .catch(e =>  this.admobFree.banner.hide());
  }
```